# AWS CloudFront Signed Cookies CORS Issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I am getting following error with cloudfront signed cookies implementation

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://a.xyz.com/test.html' from origin
>   'https://b.xyz.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I am accessing a file at a.xyz.com (Domain 1) from b.xyz.com (Domain 2).
This was working fine before restricting viewer access(using Signed cookie) for cloud front (Domain 1) distribution.

My S3 CORS configuration for bucket having domain 1 assets is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I have tried setting following whitelist headers in cloudfront behavior settings

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Request-Method
Origin
```

But I am still getting the above error.

**Note**: If I open the file https://a.xyz.com/test.html in new tab it is working fine i.e. signed cookies are created successfully.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score -1):

For CORS to be used with cookies, you need to use `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Also `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must not be `*`, and XHR need to be fired with `withCredentials`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials